# Wordpress Translated Page Have a Different Layout While Having The Same Stylesheet

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

I'm using woocommerce and wpml. I translate the check out page to Indonesian by duplicating it. But when I go to the Indonesian page, I get a different layout.

Here is two screenshots of my checkout page.
English page: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mst1jj2svu99zmk/cekot.JPG?dl=0 
Indonesian page: https://www.dropbox.com/s/eauj8bhjr1ccvtk/cekot2.JPG?dl=0

How can I make these 2 pages have the same layout?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include my question. I've edited it now.